# Make ListView show visual "can not scroll" feedback

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make ListView show visual "can not scroll" feedback when list is shorter that screen length?

Comment: Why do you need that? It won't scroll either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this behaviour is available using `setOverScrollMode` [setOverScrollMode documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29)